# Optimising Large SQL Server Tables

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, sql-server-2012, database-partitioning

I have a very large table with around 50 million rows and 15 columns. Whenever I read, I always need all columns so I can't split them. I have a clustered index on the table with 4 keys and I always read data using those keys.

But the performance is still slow, my queries are fairy simple like this

```
select 
    CountryId, RetailerID, FY, 
    sum(col1), sum(col2),.....sum(col15) 
from mytable a
join product p on a.productid = p.id
join ......
join .....
join ......
join .....
Where .......
group by CountryId, RetailerID, FY
```

I'm not using any `IN` operator or any sub queries here on any inline functions... which I know obviously make it slow. I've looked at partitioning but not sure about that, can I get some performance improvement by doing partition?

OR is there anything else I can do?

I'm using SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition

Please help!

Comment: Do all the ~50 million rows get updated regularly or are some historical and won't get updated?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the plan for the query?

Comment: I agree, please let's first see the execution plan.

Comment: Yes, they do get updated once a day but we can't control that as the SSIS packages do that whenever there is data to import. The system is integrated with SAP so I'm talking about lot of data. We've  4 tables of this size having around 50 million rows each and when we do reporting we combine them all using UNION ALL.

I've checked the query plans and they seems to be my indexes well, it doesn't display me any help that "try creating index with..." something like that so the plan is fine but it's just the problem with the data, there is too much to scan.

Comment: Whenever we pick data we pick for one Country and for the current and previous year so I was thinking to create partitions for each country and FY may be. I've around 20 countries and FYs (currently we have 2009-2014) are growing every year but users don't browse more than 2 FYs at a time.

Comment: Can you tell us which 4 columns make up the clustering key, and what their datatypes are?

Comment: Keys are CountryID, RetailerID, ProductID, DateID and while fetching data we always make sure it uses the indexes by writing where like this

WHERE CountryID =?? AND RetailerID =?? AND FY =??
OR 
WHERE CountryID =?? AND FY =?? -- in case if we need all retailers data.

I also have a non-clustered index as well on this table which includes only CountryID and DateID

Comment: I'd say that 50M rows isn't a big table. Billions of rows is a big table. Have you been through all of the obvious ? Monitored the server looking for bottlenecks (IO ?), profiled your queries, examined actual execution plans, updated stats. Also - how slow is slow ?

Comment: @bhs That is the worry, I've only up to 50m and it takes around 3 minutes, I've checked the query plan and it takes 84% on clustered index seek on main table. Stats and Indexes are always up to date as we've a maintenance plan which keeps them up to date on daily basis. Not sure about the IO but it shouldn't be worry as we've a pretty massive server.

Comment: Do you have an index the covers the 4 keys/ids?

Comment: If the query plan reports that most of the time spent is on the clustered index seek, then it's pretty much an IO bottleneck. SET STATISTICS IO ON and let us know what those numbers are. Also, run your query twice. See if the second run is not dramatically faster with no physical reads.

Comment: What's the data type of the key columns?

Comment: Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Targets'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Comment: Table 'BaseVolumeDayCurrent'. Scan count 5, logical reads 67950, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#Retailers__________________________________0000000050E8'. Scan count 2, logical reads 173, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Calendar'. Scan count 2, logical reads 296, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Comment: Table 'Calendar'. Scan count 2, logical reads 296, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Product'. Scan count 1, logical reads 633, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'EventPL'. Scan count 5, logical reads 28556, physical reads 2, read-ahead reads 5839, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Comment: Table 'Scenario'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Event'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1226, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 948, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'EventScenarios'. Scan count 1, logical reads 66, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Comment: Table 'EventProduct'. Scan count 1, logical reads 653, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 429, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Comment: Sorry one more thing, all my queries are dynamic ones. How do I paste my query here, its too long?

Comment: The query takes 50 seconds and returns 237 rows

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I have done this using aggregated tables. I run a job to aggregate data overnight which has limited the number of rows and the reports are running fine now